# Configure Git to use local configuration files instead of a Roaming Profile

Tags: git, git-for-windows

I use [Git for Windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows) with Roaming Profiles. The configuration files (`.gitconfig`) are on a network share, which seem to slow down Git sometimes. How can I move the config file to a local drive?

Answer (score 0):

Git for Windows uses a wrapper which checks `%HOME%` for the location of the configuration files. ([`git-wrapper.c`](https://github.com/git-for-windows/MINGW-packages/blob/master/mingw-w64-git/git-wrapper.c#L136)). Therefore the following should do the trick

```
setx HOME c:\Users\username
```